# Filter list of dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, filter

filter the dictionary based on filter criteria

```
records = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "all", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "sedan", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "hatchback", "year": "2010"},
]

filter_value = {
    "model": ["suv"]
}

filter_record = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2010"},
]
```

**records:**  records is the list of unfiltered data
**filter_value :**  filter_value is the search criteria
**filter_record:** it is the final data after filter, if the filter value is not present in the records, then need to check if there are any records that has 'all' as value
for example :-

```
records = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "all", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "sedan", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "hatchback", "year": "2010"},
]

filter_value = {
    "model": ["truck"]
}

filter_record = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "all", "year": "2010"},
]
```

in the above example 'truck' is not present in any of the record, so we need to bring out model = 'all'

my code:-

```
filter_value = {
    "model": ["suv"]
}

filter_record = list(filter(lambda item: (item["model"] in filter_value.get("model") or item["model"] == "all"), records))
print(filter_record)
```

output:-

```
[{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'suv', 'year': '2010'}, {'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'all', 'year': '2010'}]
```

can someone help me what I'm missing here, I'm new to python

the expected output should be:-

```
[{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'suv', 'year': '2010'}]
```

**UPDATED:**

new example-

```
records = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "F35", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "hatchback", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "ALL", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "F35", "year": "ALL"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "2022"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "ALL"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "ALL", "year": "2022"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "airline", "model": "747", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "airline", "model": "747", "year": "2022"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "airline", "model": "747", "year": "2030"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "helicopters", "model": "hingeless", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "helicopters", "model": "teetering", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "helicopters", "model": "ALL", "year": "ALL"}
    ]
```

filter_value:

```
filter_value= {
    "category" : ["aircraft"],
    "model": ["F35","blackhawk","suv","747","sedan"], 
    "year": ["2019","2022","2025"]
    }
```

expected output:

```
filter_record = [
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "F35", "year": "2019"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["F35"], "year": ["2019"]
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "F35", "year": "ALL"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["F35"], "year": ["2022"], we have record with "caregory" = "aircraft" and "model" = "F35" but not year = 2022, at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" = "aircraft"  "model" = "F35" "year"= "ALL"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "F35", "year": "ALL"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["F35"], "year": ["2025"], we have record with "caregory" = "aircraft" and "model" = "F35" but not year = 2025, at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" = "aircraft"  "model" = "F35" "year"= "ALL"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "2019"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["blackhawk"], "year": ["2019"]
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "2022"},# search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["blackhawk"], "year": ["2022"]
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "ALL"},# search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["blackhawk"], "year": ["2025"], we have record with "caregory" = "aircraft" and "model" = "blackhawk" but not year = 2025, at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" = "aircraft"  "model" = "blackhawk" "year"= "ALL"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "ALL", "year": "2019"},# search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["suv"], "year": ["2019"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' and "year" ='2019' but not "model" = "suv", at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" ="aircraft",  "model" = "ALL", "year" = "2019"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "ALL", "year": "2022"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["suv"], "year": ["2022"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' and "year" ='2022' but not "model" = "suv", at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" ="aircraft",  "model" = "ALL", "year" = "2022"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "helicopters", "model": "ALL", "year": "ALL"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["suv"], "year": ["2025"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' but not "model" = "suv" nor and "year" ='2025', at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" ="aircraft",  "model" = "ALL", "year" = "ALL"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "airline", "model": "747", "year": "2019"},# search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["747"], "year": ["2019"]
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "airline", "model": "747", "year": "2022"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["747"], "year": ["2022"]
    {}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["747"], "year": ["2025"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' and model = "747" but we do not have year = '2025' or year = 'ALL'
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "ALL", "year": "2019"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["sedan"], "year": ["2019"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' and "year" ='2019' but not "model" = "sedan", at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" ="aircraft",  "model" = "ALL", "year" = "2019"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "ALL", "year": "2022"}, # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["sedan"], "year": ["2022"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' and "year" ='2022' but not "model" = "sedan", at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" ="aircraft",  "model" = "ALL", "year" = "2022"
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "helicopters", "model": "ALL", "year": "ALL"} # search combination = "category" : ["aircraft"],  "model": ["sedan"], "year": ["2025"], we have record with "caregory" = 'aircraft' but not "model" = "sedan" nor and "year" ='2025', at this time we need to check if we have record with "category" ="aircraft",  "model" = "ALL", "year" = "ALL"
]
```

Comment: I do not get that output, I get a list with a single item, the one you expected. Please alaways provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you intend to always search by model, or could you find yourself searching by other fields, like "year", or "category"?

Comment: @Vin, yes searching can done by other fields also

Comment: @Vin can you have a look at the new example. Please see the inline explanation of the output

Comment: Your expected outputs don't include items that ought to be returned according to the logic of your search. For instance, your search terms include "model" : "suv". Why then does your expected output not include any "suv"s? Additionally, your expected output includes duplicate records - why would you expect the same record to be returned twice within the same search? The logic of your search is unclear to me, can you please clarify what behaviour you're expecting?

Comment: @Vin. I'm so sorry to make the question complicated. 
I have created a simple one now-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448500/search-and-filter-list-of-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
records = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "all", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "sedan", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "hatchback", "year": "2010"},
]

filter_value = {
    "model": ["suv", "sedan", "truck"]
}

out = []
for f in filter_value['model']:
    filter_record = list(filter(lambda item: item["model"] == f, records))
    if not filter_record:
        filter_record = list(filter(lambda item: item["model"] == "all", records))
    out.extend(filter_record)
print(out)
```

```
[{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'suv', 'year': '2010'}, {'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'sedan', 'year': '2010'}, {'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'all', 'year': '2010'}]
```

Comment: This code does the same thing, just in an unnecessarily complicated way.

Comment: Thanks. if we have multiple values in the filter_value. this seems not working as expected..can you check the above updated example

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple search terms, an approach like this might work. It's computationally inelegant, but gives you fine control over what you're searching for:

```
# Records is always a list of dictionaries. Every dictionary has exactly the same
# keys as the others. 

# Any record that has a key whose value is "all", will be returned for any search
# that includes that field. For instance, below, any search for any particular
# model will always return the second record - because whatever "model" you search
# for, "all" meets that description. 

records = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "all", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "sedan", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "hatchback", "year": "2010"},
    ]


# search_terms is a dictionary where every key must be one of the keys of one of the
# dictionaries comprising records above. Every value is a list of strings. 

search_terms = {
    "model": ["suv", "sedan"]
    }


def search_records(records, search_terms):
    """
    Returns a list of dictionaries, each dictionary being a single record from 
    "records" above.
    """
    filter_record = [] # Initiate an empty list to hold the returned records.
    # step through every key in "search_terms"
    for search_field, terms in search_terms.items(): 
        # within that key, step through every specific value searched for
        for term in terms:
            # search through every record in records
            for record in records:
                if all([record not in filter_record, (record[search_field] == term or record[search_field] == 'all')]):
                    filter_record.append(record)
                    
    return filter_record

filter_record = search_records(records, search_terms)

for record in filter_record:
    print (record)
```

Output:

```
{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'suv', 'year': '2010'}
{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'all', 'year': '2010'}
{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'sedan', 'year': '2010'}
```

To validate that it works with different types of records and multiple search terms, change your records to this:

```
records = [
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "suv", "year": "2010"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "fixed wing", "model": "F35", "year": "2019"},
    {"category": "aircraft", "type": "rotary wing", "model": "blackhawk", "year": "1999"},
    {"category": "automobile", "type": "car", "model": "hatchback", "year": "2010"},
    ]
```

and your search terms to:

```
search_terms = {
    "model": ["suv"],
    "category" : ["aircraft"]
    }
```

and calling the same function you get this output:

```
{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'suv', 'year': '2010'}
{'category': 'aircraft', 'type': 'fixed wing', 'model': 'F35', 'year': '2019'}
{'category': 'aircraft', 'type': 'rotary wing', 'model': 'blackhawk', 'year': '1999'}
```

Similarly changing the search terms to

```
search_terms = {
    "type" : ["fixed wing"], 
    "model" : ["hatchback"]
    }
```

gives you:

```
{'category': 'aircraft', 'type': 'fixed wing', 'model': 'F35', 'year': '2019'}
{'category': 'automobile', 'type': 'car', 'model': 'hatchback', 'year': '2010'}
```

Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, the output is not the expected one here, I have updated the question with one more example. Can you have a look at that.